# How to prove this identity $H=M-\dfrac{\sigma^2}{M}?$

Tags: analysis

> Let
>   $$M=\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{m}x_{i}}{m},H=\dfrac{m}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{m}\dfrac{1}{x_{i}}},\sigma^2=\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{m}(x_{i}-M)^2}{m}$$
>   show that
>   $$H=M-\dfrac{\sigma^2}{M}?$$

I think that maybe there is some elegant way to prove that 
$$\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{m}x_{i}}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{m}\dfrac{1}{x_{i}}}+\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{m}(x_{i}-M)^2}{m}=\left(\dfrac{ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{m}x_{i}}{m}\right)^2$$
or
$$\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{m}x^2_{i}}{m}=2M^2-HM$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think  this identity is wrong

take $$x_{1}=1,x_{2}=2,x_{3}=3$$
then
$$M=2,H=\dfrac{18}{11},\sigma^2=\dfrac{2}{3}$$
But
$$H\neq M-\dfrac{\sigma^2}{M}$$